# Camera not working Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, camera

I am trying to use camera through my iphone app. In the phonegap documentation, i found `camera.getpicture` and `capture.captureImage` methods. I tried both these methods but no success.

I deployed the sample code on my `iphone 4` but nothing happens when this method gets called. Its as if it is totally ignored.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470977/phonegap-camera-api-not-working-for-ios

Comment: navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 40, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 

I have this statement. But nothing happens

Comment: do you have the success and fail functions, and are they being properly called?

Comment: yes. i do have them. but the camera isnt even opening for a snap

Comment: Have you tried taking the camera example and just implementing that? Results? Not just the snippets but the whole example?

Comment: yes. i have tried that. and it did not give any result. 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html
 I tried everything from this website but nothing happens in any of the programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what i got wrong. Phonegap 1.0.0 camera was not working for iPhone 4. But when i used Phonegap 1.3.0. It worked like a charm. I hate these compatibilities.